# Protection for 'system' attributes in ActiveRecord new table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I use ***rails 4.1.6*** and ***ruby 2.2.0***

When I create a table without any columns like that:

`create_table "carts", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end`

The table has a three (with some protection?) field: ***id***, ***created_at***, ***updated_at***

I think that I can't edit or create object with custom ***id*** and other fields, but when I wrote my unit test:

```
assert Cart.create(id: 'abc', created_at: '2014-05-19').invalid?
```

It fails, because I can overwrite ***id*** field. How can I protected and how even possible this strange behavior?!

If needed ***Controller:***

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :invalid_cart

  # GET /carts
  # GET /carts.json
  def index
    @carts = Cart.all
  end

  # GET /carts/1
  # GET /carts/1.json
  def show

  end

  # GET /carts/new
  def new
    @cart = Cart.new
  end

  # GET /carts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /carts
  # POST /carts.json
  def create
    @cart = Cart.new(cart_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @cart.save
        format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cart }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /carts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /carts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @cart.update(cart_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @cart }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /carts/1
  # DELETE /carts/1.json
  def destroy
    @cart = current_cart
    @cart.destroy
    session[:cart_id] = nil
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to store_url, notice: '' }
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_cart
        @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def cart_params
      params[:cart]
    end

    def invalid_cart
      logger.error " #{params[:id]}"
      redirect_to store_url, notice: ''
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normally handled through [strong parameters](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html). You have bypassed this in your `cart_params` method, it should rather look something like this:

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def cart_params
  params.require(:cart).permit(:attribute1, :attribute2, ...)
end
```

Other attributes not present in the whitelist will be discarded. Then, the method finally does what its comment says ;-)

Comment: If they're discard how this line of code in UNIT test create a REAL(because I get some field from other table link with this table) object: assert Cart.create(id: 'abc', created_at: '2014-05-19').invalid?

Comment: Your test does not test the controller, it tests the model. It is a good thing that you can set the values internally, e.g. for data import. The controller will filter values coming from the user, that is enough to prevent mass assignment issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should restrict card_params using strong parameters.

There is example:

```
def card_params
  params.require(:card).permit(:all, :your, :card, :attributes, 
    :that, :you, :want, :to, :allow, :in, :form
   )
end
```

Comment: Yep, I know it, but I haven't any r/w attributes, look at my scheme.rb ;) I only have a SYSTEM fields like :id, :created_at (for more, :id — generate automatic, unique and be a foreigner_key)... Really strange that in rails 3.x it was attr_protected from default and you can't edit it, at least in mass assignment.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need disallow application wide to set those fields on create or update. Furthermore there a good example when you need to set those fields, for example when working with data from legacy applications or when you implement mass imports.

To protect an object is not the reposibility of the object itself. Protection and access controll is the responsibily of the controller. Because different controllers might have different requirements (e.g. user facing controller vs. admin controller). This was the reason why `attr_protected` was removed and `strong_parameters` were introduced.